Clicking on Radio button should change textbox to dropdown list
I have a text box and 2 radio buttons in my ASP.Net Core MVC web page as shown below:

If the "Existing" radio button is clicked, the text box should change to a dropdown list. And if the "New" radio button is clicked, the dropdown list should be changed to the textbox. Since I am very new the web technology, I don't know how to do it. please help.


.table1 {
  display: inline-block
}
<div class="table1">
  <label> Level 3 Num</label>
  <input type="text" name="text1" class="l3n" placeholder="Level 3 Num" maxlength="100" style="margin:5px;width:400px; height:30px;border:1px solid #01579B;" />
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="editList" value="new" />New
      </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="editList" value="existing" />Existing
      </label>
</div>




You need to add an eventListener to your radio buttons that will run a function and make the desired changes.

@pierpy can you not see the <style> code?

Here is a version based on Mehdi's code, but using delegation and setting initial list based on default checked


const container = document.querySelector('.table1'),
  dataListInput = document.getElementById('datalist-input'),
  initial = document.querySelector('[name=editList]:checked').value,
  toggleList = (val) => dataListInput.setAttribute('list', val === 'new' ? "" : "datalist")

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('[name=editList]')) return; // not a radio
  toggleList(tgt.value);
});

toggleList(initial);
.table1 {
  display: inline-block
}
<div class="table1">
  <label for="datalist-input">Level 3 Num</label>
  <input list="datalist" type="text" id="datalist-input" name="text1" id="datalist-input" class="l3n" placeholder="Level 3 Num" maxlength="100" style="margin:5px;width:400px; height:30px;border:1px solid #01579B;" />
  <datalist id="datalist">
    <option value="Chocolate"></option>
    <option value="Coconut"></option>
    <option value="Mint"></option>
    <option value="Strawberry"></option>
    <option value="Vanilla"></option>
  </datalist>
  <label><input type="radio" name="editList" value="new" checked />New</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="editList" value="existing" />Existing</label>
</div>




You can use the following code as suggested by @Yogi using datalist. You also need to use an event listener for each radio button. I used conditional ternary operator (same as if statement) to remove or keep the list attribute on the input box. You just need to add the code to read your input value


const dataList = document.getElementById('datalist')
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio')
const dataListInput = document.getElementById('datalist-input')

radios.forEach((radio)=>{
    radio.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
        radio.value == 'new' ? dataListInput.setAttribute('list',"") : dataListInput.setAttribute('list',"datalist")
    })
})
.table1 {
    display: inline-block
  }
<div class="table1">
        <label for="datalist-input"> Level 3 Num</label> 
        <input list="datalist" type="text" id="datalist-input" name="text1" id="datalist-input" class="l3n" placeholder="Level 3 Num" maxlength="100" style="margin:5px;width:400px; height:30px;border:1px solid #01579B;" />
        <datalist id="datalist">
            <option value="Chocolate"></option>
            <option value="Coconut"></option>
            <option value="Mint"></option>
            <option value="Strawberry"></option>
            <option value="Vanilla"></option>
        </datalist>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="editList" value="new" />New
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="editList" value="existing" />Existing
        </label>
      </div>




Hi @Mehdi....thanks for your answer. It is also working.

@sofiya kalan you are very welcome and glad that it helped. Enjoy coding!
